# How to skip a test in pytest based on command-line option / fixture

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I have a pytest suite containing multiple files that test web services. The tests can be run on different types, call them type A and type B and the user can specify which type the tests should be run for. While most tests are applicable for type A and B, some are not applicable for type B. I need to be able to skip certain tests when pytest is run with the --type=B flag.

Here is my conftest.py file where I setup a fixture based on type

```
import pytest

#Enable type argument
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--type", action="store", default="A", help = "Specify a content type, allowed values: A, B")

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def type(request):
    if request.node.get_closest_marker('skipb') and request.config.getoption('--type') == 'B': 
        pytest.skip('This test is not valid for type B so it was skipped')
        print("Is type B")
    return request.config.getoption("--type")
```

Then, before my test function to be skipped I am adding the marker as follows:

```
class TestService1(object):

    @pytest.mark.skipb()
    def test_status(self, getResponse):
        assert_that(getResponse.ok, "HTTP Request OK").is_true()
        printResponse(getResponse)

class TestService2(object):

    @pytest.mark.skipb()
    def test_status(self, getResponse):
        assert_that(getResponse.ok, "HTTP Request OK").is_true()
        printResponse(getResponse)
```

I am able to run pytest and don't get any interpreter errors however it doesn't skip my test. Here is the command I use to run the test:

```
pytest -s --type=B
```

Update: I need to clarify that my tests are spread across multiple classes. Updated my code example to make this more clear.

Comment: `if request.node.get_closest_marker('mymark') and request.config.getoption('--type') == 'B': pytest.skip('cannot run')` in `type` fixture.

Comment: It still won't skip the tests, I updated my conftest above and shared the test function

Comment: Remove `scope="session"` from fixture. It should be executed once for every test, not once per test session.

Comment: That didn't exactly work but did lead me to my own solution. I am new to pytest so if you could help me understand this better it would be great. Basically my project has multiple files, each is it's own class which tests a rest service. The command line options apply to all these classes so that's why I have the type fixture have the scope=session which seems to be necessary. I added a new fixture to named 'skip_by_type' with the scope at the function level but that still doesn't find the makers properly. I changed this fixture to have scope="class" and can skip a full class fine this way.

Comment: I have just tried your code on my machine and it's working. If it doesn't work on yours, update the code in question to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

We use something very similar to run an "extended parameter set". For this, you can use the following code:

In conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--extended-parameter-set",
        action="store_true",
        default=False,
        help="Run an extended set of parameters.")

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    extended_parameter_set = config.getoption("--extended-parameter-set")

    skip_extended_parameters = pytest.mark.skip(
        reason="This parameter combination is part of the extended parameter "
        "set.")

    for item in items:
        if (not extended_parameter_set
                and "extended_parameter_set" in item.keywords):
            item.add_marker(skip_extended_parameters)
```

Now, you can simply mark full tests or only some parametrizations of a test with "extended_parameter_set" and it will only be run if pytest is invoked with the `--extended-parameter-set` option